# Polymorphism while posting to Web Api Controller

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a Ad Model like below:

```
public class AdModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

And I have lots of derived classes as well like.

```
public class CarAdModel : AdModel
{
    public int? Kilometer { get; set; }
}
```

My `Web Api Controller` is like:

```
public class AdController : ApiController
{
     [HttpPost]
     public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] AdModel adModel)
     {
         //db insert
         return Ok();
     }
}
```

If I post a derived object like `CarAdModel` from my `AngularJs` app, I only get those properties which belong to `AdModel`, can I get derived object on `Post` action?

Comment: You don't need `[FromBody]`. Complex types are deserialized from the body automatically

Answer (score 1):

you need create custom binder for AddModel or common binder like this and some field for restore target class:

```
public class TypeModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
        {
            var typeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + ".ModelType");
            var type = Type.GetType((string)typeValue.ConvertTo(typeof(string)), true);
            var model = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, type);
            return model;
        }
    }
```

In my example model, the field "ModelType" contais full typename of the class

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit?

Comment: You override the default binder. In my case, the field "ModelType" contains the name of a class type, I recreate delivered object by classname string using Activator. you can use someelse flag

Comment: Thanks a lot, this one only helped me.